# Configure error logging - path broken

Tags: php, wordpress

Configure error logging.

I'm working with PHP, and I'm on the support side, but I do not know the error system. Is there any material I can read to help me?

My biggest problem is this, many errors are written to the log this way:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'vc-icon-element.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\js_composer\config\conte on line 6
```

But it seems the path is not complete and I do not know which file made the request for `vc-icon-element.php`. How would I do to find out which file or page that generated this log? Is it normal that the path does not reach a `.php` file?

Comment: _I do not know which file made the request for vc-icon-element.php_ The error tells you that .... `in D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\js_composer\config\conte on line 6` it even gives you the line number

Comment: But the "/ conte" is not a file or a folder.

Comment: I'm guessing the line is getting truncated - it shouldn't, but maybe there is a setting in php.ini shoretning the default (the default should be 1024 bytes - ie, 1kB) - look here http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors-max-len

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me.